# AngularJS, how do you get a `select` to refresh automatically?

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with 'select' when I choose an option in 1st 'select' I don't see the result in same time in the 2nd 'select', I must refresh the page manually with 'F5' so I can see the results. 
**add_parcelle.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.type.$dirty && Form.type.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.type.$valid}">
            <label for="form-field-select-2">
                Type de la parcelle <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <select name="type" ng-model="type" title="select" class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic" ng-change="sendType(Form.type.$modelValue)" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Selectionnez un type</option>
                <option value="Lot">Lot</option>
                <option value="Parcelle">Parcelle</option>
                <option value="Zone">Zone</option>
                <option value="Plant">Plant</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.type.$dirty && Form.type.$invalid">Champ bligatoire</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.idParcelle.$dirty && Form.idParcelle.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.idParcelle.$valid && Form.idParcelle.$dirty}">
            <label for="form-field-select-2">
                Parent de la parcelle <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <select data-ng-init="showParents()" name="idParcelle" ng-model="idParcelle" title="select" class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Selectionnez un parent</option>
                <option value="1">Aucun parent</option>
                <option ng-repeat="p in parcelle" value="{{p.idParcelle}}"><div ng-if="p.parent.libelle">{{p.libelle}}</div></option>
            </select>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.idParcelle.$dirty && Form.idParcelle.$invalid">Champ bligatoire</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ParcelleController.js**

```
$scope.sendType= function(type){

    $sessionStorage.typeParc=type;
    console.log($sessionStorage.typeParc);

};
$scope.showParents = function() {


    if($sessionStorage.typeParc=='Parcelle')
        $scope.showLots();
    else if($sessionStorage.typeParc=='Zone')
        $scope.showParcels();
        else if($sessionStorage.typeParc=='Plant')
            $scope.showZones();


};
```

**In 1st 'Select' I use:**

> ng-change="sendType(Form.type.$modelValue)"

so I can store the Form.type and use it in function showParents() that show the result in 2nd 'Select'

> data-ng-init="showParents()"

So, this is my problem!!
thanks in advance :)

after edit of 'Gustavo Gabriel'
**this is the result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvrXD.jpg)

I don't see the list in 'select' but I see it in console :p

Comment: Too much indent in html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first select modify your ng-change to:

```
ng-change="sendType(Form.type.$modelValue); showParents();"
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: thanks Bro, it's works but not 100% look at this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvrXD.jpg I don't see the result il 'select'

Comment: Are you sure you have a libelle attribute in the objects?

Comment: yeah I have libelle attribute in the objects. It's works now. It was a problem of cache :p
thanks Bro.